# Sort main list based on date field in nested list Java

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

I have below list of objects and need to sort this based on ingredients bestbefore date. So the recipes that have the oldest best before date should come last in the list.

```
 [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "recipeName": "Burger",
        "createdDate": "2020-11-22T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "ingredientId": 3,
                "ingredientName": "Burger Bun",
                "category": "",
                "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                "bestBefore": "2020-12-23"
            },
            {
                "ingredientId": 4,
                "ingredientName": "Beef Pattie",
                "category": "",
                "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                "bestBefore": "2020-12-23"
            },
            {
                "ingredientId": 5,
                "ingredientName": "Tomato",
                "category": "",
                "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                "bestBefore": "2020-09-10"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "recipeName": "Chicken Salad",
        "createdDate": "2020-11-22T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "ingredientId": 7,
                "ingredientName": "Chicken",
                "category": "",
                "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                "bestBefore": "2020-12-23"
            },
            {
                "ingredientId": 6,
                "ingredientName": "Salad Mix",
                "category": "",
                "useBy": "2020-12-20",
                "bestBefore": "2020-11-15"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried below code but it's only sorting ingredients within the recipe not the recipe object in the list. Is this possible with Java 8 Streams?

```
List<Recipes> finalList = filteredList.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> (int) (o1.getId() - o2.getId()))
        .map(recipes -> {
            List<Ingredients> in = recipes.getIngredients().stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Ingredients::getBestBefore).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            recipes.setIngredients(in);
            return recipes;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: when you said sort based on ingredients best before date, which ingredient shall be considered for the overall recipe to be sorted? (think of ingredients with worst and best value for `bestBefore` value to be a part of the same recipe, what would be the position for this recipe ini your sorted list?)

Comment: @Naman if any ingredient has oldest `bestbeforedate` that recipe should come last in the list. In this case Burger object should come last in the list since tomato has the oldest `bestBeforedate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to make sure that *if any ingredient has oldest `bestBefore` date that recipe should come last in the list.* You would require to identify the `max`(oldest) date amongst ingredients of a recipe, for which you can create a method such as follows:

```
private static Date findOldestBestBeforeForRecipe(Recipes recipes) {
    return recipes.getIngredients()
            .stream()
            .map(Ingredients::getBestBefore)
            .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("recipes without ingredients!!"));
}
```

then sorting your recipes, would simplify such as defining a `Comparator<Recipes>` for this criteria and appending them to existing comparison.

```
Comparator<Recipes> ingredientsBestBeforeDate = (o1, o2) ->
        findOldestBestBeforeForRecipe(o2).compareTo(findOldestBestBeforeForRecipe(o1));

List<Recipes> finalList = filteredList.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Recipes::getId)
                .thenComparing(ingredientsBestBeforeDate))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This isn't the result I am expecting, any recipe containing ingredients old bestbefore (recipe should sort based on bestbefore ) dates should be place to bottom of the list

Comment: After edit your answer could achieved the result 
`List<Recipes> finalList = filteredList.stream().sorted(ingredientsBestBeforeDate).collect(Collectors.toList());`

And below fix in `findOldestBestBeforeForRecipe`
`.min(Comparator.naturalOrder())`